# Understanding a proof that the deformation functor satisfies the third Schlessinger Criterion $\textbf{H3}$

Tags: deformation-theory

I am trying to understand Gouvêa's proof (Lemma 3.7, page 43 [here](https://typo.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/fileadmin/_migrated/media/Gouvea-2001-Deformations_of_Galois_representations.pdf)) that Schlessinger's criterion $\textbf{H3}$ holds for the deformation functor $D_\Lambda$ for a complete noetherian local ring $\Lambda$ with finite residue field $k$, where we have some fixed residual representation $\bar{\rho}:\Pi \to \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ of a profinite group $\Pi$ that satisfies Mazur's $p$-finiteness condition. There are two steps in the proof that I do not understand.

The criterion $\textbf{H3}$ states that the tangent space
$$
t_{D_\Lambda} = D_\Lambda(k[\varepsilon])
$$
is a finite-dimensional vector space over $k$, where $k[\varepsilon] = k[x]/(x^2)$ is the ring of dual numbers. Since $k$ is finite, this is equivalent to $D_\Lambda(k[\varepsilon])$ being a finite set, so we want to show that there are finitely many strict equivalence classes of lifts $\rho:\Pi \to \operatorname{GL}_n(k[\varepsilon])$.

**The Proof**

Gouvêa starts by defining $\Pi_0 = \ker \bar{\rho}$, which is an open subgroup of $\Pi_0$ of finite index, since the quotient $\Pi/\Pi_0 \cong \operatorname{GL}_n(k[\varepsilon])$ is finite. For $x \in \Pi_0$, it is clear that $\rho(x) \in \Gamma_n(k[\varepsilon])$, where $\Gamma_n(k[\varepsilon]) = 1 + \varepsilon\operatorname{GL}_n(k[\varepsilon])$ is the kernel of the projection $\operatorname{GL}_n(k[\varepsilon]) \to \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$. Therefore each lift $\rho$ gives a map
$$
\Pi_0 \to \Gamma_n(k[\varepsilon]).
$$
Now Gouvea makes the first claim that I don't understand. He says that if two lifts determine the same map $\Pi_0\to \Gamma_n(k[\varepsilon])$, then they are identical. I do not see why this is true. We will call this $\textbf{Difficulty 1}$.

Next Gouvêa refers to problem $3.23$, which has us show that $\Gamma_n(k[\varepsilon])$ is a finite $p$-elementary abelian group. He says that it follows by $p$-finiteness that there are finitely many maps $\Pi_0 \to \Gamma_n(k[\varepsilon])$. We will call this $\textbf{Difficulty 2}$.

The conclusion then follows easily.

**My Difficulties**

We discuss $\textbf{Difficulties 1&2}$

For $\textbf{Difficulty 1}$, the claim is equivalent to showing that if a lift $\rho$ takes every element of $\Pi_0$ to the identity matrix $I_n$, then there is only one possibility for $\rho$. If $\rho$ has this property, then $\rho$ descends to a homomorphism
$$
\varphi:\operatorname{GL}_n(k) = \Pi/\Pi_0 \to \operatorname{GL}_n(k[\varepsilon]),
$$
such that $\pi\circ\varphi = \operatorname{id}$, where $\pi:k[\varepsilon]\to k$ is the natural projection. So I want to show that there is at most one such homomorphism. Since the natural inclusion satisfies this property, we want to show that $\varphi$ is the canonical inclusion. I have thought about writing the map $\varphi$ in the form
$$
\varphi(A) = A + \varepsilon \tilde{A},
$$
where $\tilde{A} \in M_n(k)$. Then it is easy to see that $\widetilde{AB} = \tilde{A} + \tilde{B}$ for all $A, B$, so it would suffice to show that there is no nonzero homomorphism from the multiplicative group $\operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ to the additive group $M_n(k)$. This is true for $n=1$, since the groups have coprime order, but I'm having trouble proving it for general $n$.

As for $\textbf{Difficulty 2}$, I have two sub-difficulties. First of all, I am suspicious of my justification that $\Gamma_n(k[\varepsilon])$ is a $p$-elementary. I think that the map
$$
\varphi:M_n(k) \to I_n + \varepsilon M_n(k) = \Gamma_n(k[\varepsilon])
$$
given by
$$
\varphi(A) = I_n + \varepsilon A
$$
is an isomorphism from the additive group $M_n(k)$ to the multiplicative group $\Gamma_n(k[\varepsilon])$, since
$$
\varphi(A)\varphi(B) = (I_n + \varepsilon A)(I_n + \varepsilon B) = I_n + \varepsilon(A + B) = \varphi(A+B),
$$
because $\epsilon^2 = 0$. However, this implies that $\Gamma_n(k[\varepsilon])$ has order $\lvert k \rvert^n$, which makes it a $p$-group. This is stronger than being $p$-elementary, so I suspect that I am wrong, because the question only asks for it to be $p$-elementary.

This issue aside, I don't see why the $p$-finiteness condition implies that there are finitely many maps $\Pi_0 \to \Gamma_n(k[\varepsilon])$. The $p$-finiteness condition tells us that there are finitely many continuous maps to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for each prime $p$. It seems obvious to use the classification of finite abelian groups, which tells us that any finite abelian group is a direct product of cylic $p$-groups. However, if one of these cyclic groups has order $p^n$ for $n\geq 2$, then the $p$-finiteness condition doesn't apply, and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any help would be very much appreciated.